# How to rotate an orientation (Euler angles)

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems, rotations, orientation

If I have an orientation defined by Euler angles and I want to simulate a rotation of the coordinate system about the origin (doesn't matter to me how the rotation is specified), how would I get the new Euler angles? I understand how to transform a point via a rotation matrix, but I'm not sure how to approach this in terms of Euler angles.

For example, I'm thinking of an airplane's orientation in terms of pitch, yaw, and roll, and say I want to simulate a random rotation of the airplane about its center.

Comment: The rotation matrix is given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix

Comment: How would I apply the rotation matrix to my original Euler angles?

Comment: You just compute it from the Euler angles !

Comment: Thanks for the comment but you are misunderstanding my question. How do I apply (not compute) such a rotation transformation to an orientation (as specified via Euler angles) as opposed to points in 3-space?

Comment: I guess that the only way is to multiply the rotation matrices and inverse the process to retrieve the Euler angles corresponding to the combined rotations (see my answer about this).